# [OpenAPI 3]Load different schema based on enum selection

Tags: yaml, swagger, openapi

I am trying to write some documentation for an API according to OpenAPI 3 specifications. What I want to achieve is to load a different `schema` each time an `enum` changes.

For example, I have this parameter.

```
parameters: 
        - description: The operation code (OC)
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/OperationCode'
          name: oc
          in: query
```

which has this schema:

```
components:
  schemas:
    OperationCode:
      type: string
      enum:
        - Operation1
        - Operation2
```

Now, below, I have another parameter that I want it to be dynamically changed based on the previous enum selection:

```
- description: Required parameters for selected operation code
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: ????
          name: parameters
          in: "body"
```

And lets say I want to choose between these two schemas:

```
components:
  schemas:
    Operation1:
      properties:
        id1:
          type: integer
    Operation2:
      properties:
        id2:
          type: integer
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
...
schema:
  oneOf:
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Operation1'
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Operation2'
```

That will not force the correct object to the enum parameter value. But you can describe the possible schemas and explain the enum <-> operation association in the description.

See also [openapi "of" keywords](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/oneof-anyof-allof-not/#oneof).

Comment: This does not help me much to achieve what I need. Is there another way to let's say get the value from the `enum` selected and concatenate in order to create the path to the proper schema?

Comment: .. I guess I don't understand what you want to do.